# How to Paste Complex Transfer Function Equation to Excel

Tags: filtering, control-systems

I am trying to paste this transfer function to Excel, is it possible?

[image]

Comment: There is no equation in your code.

Comment: You are not giving us enough to work on your problem. [We expect](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic):
❌ A clear description of an on-topic problem or goal.
❌ A minimal working *Wolfram Language* code example, formatted, easy to *copy&paste*, in [Raw InputForm](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/menuitem/RawInputForm.html). 
❌ An example of what you expect as output.
❌ Some proof of minimal *Mathematica* knowledge.
❌ Minimum due diligence: Share how you have searched the site and documentation, your attempts and reasons to believe an answer exists.

Comment: I would not assume people here would know which formats Excel accepts for an equation. Do you know? Furthermore, I suggest that if you are doing anything serious, other than accounting, Excel is not the tool you want to use.  Also not clear if this question is even on-topic. Please [edit] your question to improve it.

Answer (score 1):

In Mathematica, enter

```
f=..yourexpressionabove..;
excelf=f/.{R->A1,W->B1, Subscript[C,1]->C1,Subscript[C,2]->D1,
  Subscript[L,1]->E1,Subscript[L,2]->F1, Subscript[L,m]->G1}//InputForm
```

That replaces all your Mathematica variable names with Excel cell references in the first row of your spreadsheet.

Then use your mouse to scrape the output from that into your clipboard.

In Excel click in cell A2, type = and then paste your clipboard contents into the rest of that cell.

You have now pasted your function from Mathematica into Excel.

Fill the cells in first row with values and the second row should show you the result of your calculation.

Comment: Mr. Bill thank you for help. It was very usefull. I can make it easily.